# Mounting shared folder in VirtualBox 6.1 for Ubuntu 20.04 (Windows host) not working

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-20.04, guest-additions

I followed https://www.pragmaticlinux.com/2021/02/how-to-mount-a-shared-folder-in-virtualbox/(among other related threads) in order to mount a shared folder in my Ubuntu 20.04 VM.

**Auto-mounting**

I created an entry under VirtualBox Ubuntu 20.04 VM Settings -> Shared Folders and completed the ***Folder Path*** to a valid Windows(host) location, the ***Folder Name*** (called shared) and checked ***Auto-mount*** and ***Make Permanent***. I left ***Mount point*** empty.

After the above setup I boot the Ubuntu 20 VM and I was expecting to see the mount under `/media/sf_shared` and I did see it however **it was empty** even though on the host machine there are several files.

**Manual mounting**

1. From VirtualBox
   In Settings -> Shared Folders dialog I unchecked Auto-mount checkbox and added a valid value in Mount point (eg. `/home/myuser/shared`). However the same behavior as for Auto-mounting happens. The share does not work, cannot see the files under the shared folder from the host machine.
2. From VM Ubuntu terminal

   `sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=$USER,gid=vboxsf shared /home/myuser/shared`

   But I get the following error:

   **`/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: Invalid argument`**

Maybe the last error that I got in terminal is a hint for the root of the problem. However I couldn't find any relevant information of how to solve it. Does anyone has any idea of what's going on here?

Also must mention that on the same VirtualBox I have another VM installed (Ubuntu 18.04) on which the auto-mounting is working as a charm.

Comment: Have you ensured that your USER is allowed to see the files? (perhaps you have).. I myself have run into this when I didn't add my user to the `vboxsf` group.. as in `sudo adduser $USER vboxsf` (followed by a reboot).  If the `vboxsf` group doesn't already exist, create it first.  I am also assuming that you have the guest additions installed with no errors.

Comment: Yes, I've added the user to vboxsf group

Comment: Bummer.. I *did* find [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/virtualbox/comments/n6vz3l/shared_folders_lost_after_update/) on reddit.  It implies that someone with the same problem solved it by backdating their version of the *guestaddition* stuff.  Worth a shot.. no? Sorry I have never encountered exactly what you are looking at.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, but it turned out that I was using an outdated version of the guestadditions. I mounted version 6.1.32 of guestadditions in the guest and then I reinstall the additions, reboot the guest and it worked.